# md-select not updating with ng-value text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

Hello i have a problem.

When i put an integer in ng-value, md-select is upadated:

```
<md-input-container>
      <md-select ng-model="test">
            <md-option ng-value="1">1</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="2">2</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="3">3</md-option>
            <md-option ng-value="4">4</md-option>
     </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

But when i do this with string value it is not working, what can i do ?

```
<md-input-container>
   <md-select ng-model="type">
        <md-option ng-value=''></md-option>
        <md-option ng-value='test' >test</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value='test02'>test02</md-option>
        <md-option ng-value='test03' >test03</md-option>
   </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `value=""` (expect a string)

This is working:

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="type">
    <md-option value=''></md-option>
    <md-option value='test' >test</md-option>
    <md-option value='test02'>test02</md-option>
    <md-option value='test03' >test03</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Or you can use `ng-value=""` (expect an expression)

```
<md-input-container>    
  <md-select ng-model="type">
    <md-option ng-value="''"></md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="'test'" >test</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="'test02'">test02</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="'test03'" >test03</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Your first example is working because integer values are correct expressions. In your second example angular is looking for a property named test in your scope.